# Why does my YouTube video look fuzzy?

Tags: youtube, video-capture, screen-capture, progressive, interlacing

I have been recording a video game series with this old Dazzle capture card. If you look at my video, you can see how the footage looks fuzzy.

I think it has something to do with my having to deinterlace it. I tried a couple different deinterlacing options, but the video just didn't look right.

The video's format is 1080p and I believe the game's native resolution is 480p. Can someone tell me how to fix this?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M5eFZp3R9Tk

Comment: I'd recommend checking out http://superuser.com for these types of non-programming questions.